# Can't get a PayPal/Braintree SDK access token

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

A simple question: I used to have a Braintree SDK test access token. Now it's gone. When I try to generate a new one, I get this:

> You don't have any sandbox Business accounts in (AU, CA, GB, FR, IT, SG, JP, DE, US, IN, C2, HK) to generate Braintree SDK test access tokens. First, please create a sandbox Business account from any of the countries listed above in order to generate a new Braintree SDK test access token.

But I do have a Business Sandbox Account in DE ... not sure what I'm doing wrong (as I said, I already had a token).
Does anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 2):

I think their Sandbox may be broken right now. My two Sandbox accounts (buyer and facilitator) have disappeared from their system though I can still log in. Payments are also failing on my test application.

Answer (score 0):

I started implementing a PayPal Checkout Workflow today and tried for several hours to create a sandbox account and app, so I could get REST API credentials. No luck until now.

It looks like their backend is broken right now.

Comment: This is not an answer!